# Android Studio is showing squares box on hindi language at string.xml file

Tags: android, hindi

I have a translation from english to Hindi and I`m adding it to Android Studio for my app, so I created the strings.xml (hi) on Android Studio.

When I copy the data from word document to the strings.xml (hi) file on Android Studio, the strings.xml (hi) Hindi characteres are shown as square box.

The strange thing is that when I run the app on mobile phone the correct Hindi language appears.

I suppose that Android Studio is not able to show the correct characters on strings.xml (hi) file.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the Hindi language on my Windows and now I can see the Hindi characteres on Android Studio.